# How to define a service as isolated programmatically without declaring it in AndroidManifest file?

Tags: android, reflection, process, android-service

I'm invoking a method from Service Manager class (ActivityManagerService.java). I am using reflection for this. I want to set isolated=True for my service from my class instead of manifest file.

Comment: Bear in mind that such reflection is being banned as part of Android P.

Comment: Yes, you've made me aware of that but do you have the solution for this one of know how it can be done?